# How to type key combinations instead of pressing them?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

Is there a way where instead of pressing the key combinations, I can activate a mode and type in the key combination in words? For example I would type in something like `control shift s` to mean the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, without actually pressing the combination. That is, I want to create verbose aliases for some difficult to reach keys and when I just type out those aliases, the machine should behave as if I had pressed the key combination instead.

I would like this to work across applications. For example it should work on my browser, on my editor etc. It should work on any future application that I may ever install.

That is I need an interface/filter/translator between my keyboard and the OS, that will translate what I type into appropriate commands or key combinations.

For example say I am in Libre Office where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> is used for Print command. Then I would want to do something like this: Type `control p` instead of pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>P</kbd> together. And that should get translated to the correct key combination and fed into Libre Office.

In particular it shouldn't matter what application I am using.

This is how I imagine it to work (I am adding all these details to explain more clearly what I am looking for):

1. Say I want to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2. Press a special key combination say <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and that would activate this "translation" mode.
3. Type `control shift r`. While typing I may use backspace. For example the key strokes may be: `com(backspace)ntri(backspace)ol S(backspace)shift,(backspace) r`. Then that should just mean `control shift r` because if I were to type that out on an editor, it would be that.
4. Press a special key combination say <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>. That would then "translate" everything that was typed between the first special key <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and the last special key <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> and send the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to the machine.

Is there a solution to the problem?

Comment: A script that uses `xdotool` to map typed words to keypresses, maybe.

Comment: Yes I have been thinking along similar lines now. I would have a python script to interpret the command. And the script would key in the combination (may be by using xdotool). I am just waiting to see if someone would have already done this.